# I want to add inspection tool in my browsing app on android studio Kotlin

Tags: inspect, web-inspector

in my browsing app on android studio Kotlin

I used this script of enable the inspect tool in browser.

javascript:(function () {      var script =  document.createElement('script');     script.src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/eruda";      document.body.appendChild(script);     script.onload = function () {          eruda.init()      }  })();

But still it is not enabling the inspection tool.